# ODE for the Fourier transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform

Consider the PDE
$$
u_t=u_{xx}+u_x+u.
$$
Fourier transforming both sides gives
$$
\hat{u}_t=(ik)^2+ik+\hat{u},~~~(*)
$$
where $\hat{u}$ is the Fourier transform of $u$.

Now, for fixed $k$, $(*)$ is an ODE in $t$.

It is said that solutions of $(*)$ are of the form
$$
\hat{u}=\exp(\lambda(k)t)\cdot v_0(k).
$$

Why?

Comment: You're missing some things after you take the Fourier transform

Comment: That isn't the correct transformed expression. After it is transformed, it only has derivatives in one variable, and can be solved as an ODE, where the constants of integration are functions of the other variable.

Comment: Oh, the right expression should be $\hat{u}_t=-k^2\hat{u}+ik \hat{u}+\hat{u}$, hence $\hat{u}_t=(-k^2+ik+1)\hat{u}$.

Comment: The "constant" which appears multiplicatively in the solution of the $t$-ODE for $\hat{u}$ is really a function of the remaining variable, namely $k$. Perhaps this notation anticipates some convolution final step...